# AngularJS stop button with ng-click?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I just started learning about AngularJS and I have trouble with code which count from 0 to 10

```
var myController = function ($scope) {
   $scope.timer = 1;
       $scope.count10 = function () {
         setInterval(function () {
             if (10 > $scope.timer) {
                 $scope.timer++;
             } 
             else {
                 $scope.timer = 1;
             };
             $scope.$apply();
             }, 1000);
        };
 };
```

I created the reset button with

```
$scope.reset = function()
        {
            $scope.timer = 0;
        }
```

Please help me to stop button, thanks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Window's setInterval() method which you have used, to stop/clear it you need to call clearInterval() method inside your reset method.

See below how to use it.

- Hold setInterval() in a variable like:

  `var yourVar = setInterval(()=> { // your code here}, 1000);`
- And to clear/stop interval, call  clearInterval() method like:

  `clearInterval(yourVar);`

For your problem, solution is as follows:

```
  var myController = function ($scope) {
  $scope.timer = 1;
   var interval;
   $scope.count10 = function () {
    interval = setInterval(function () {
         if (10 > $scope.timer) {
             $scope.timer++;
         } 
         else {
             $scope.timer = 1;
         };
         $scope.$apply();
         }, 1000);
    };

  $scope.reset = function()
    {
        $scope.timer = 0;
        //Clear/Stop interval
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
  };
```

**As you are using angular I will recommend to use '$interval' service of angular itself.**

See below [how to use](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) it:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-interval-service-production</title>
  

  <script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>
  

  
</head>
<body ng-app="intervalExample">
  <script>
  angular.module('intervalExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', '$interval',
      function($scope, $interval) {
        $scope.format = 'M/d/yy h:mm:ss a';
        $scope.blood_1 = 100;
        $scope.blood_2 = 120;

        var stop;
        $scope.fight = function() {
          // Don't start a new fight if we are already fighting
          if ( angular.isDefined(stop) ) return;

          stop = $interval(function() {
            if ($scope.blood_1 > 0 && $scope.blood_2 > 0) {
              $scope.blood_1 = $scope.blood_1 - 3;
              $scope.blood_2 = $scope.blood_2 - 4;
            } else {
              $scope.stopFight();
            }
          }, 100);
        };

        $scope.stopFight = function() {
          if (angular.isDefined(stop)) {
            $interval.cancel(stop);
            stop = undefined;
          }
        };

        $scope.resetFight = function() {
          $scope.blood_1 = 100;
          $scope.blood_2 = 120;
        };

        $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
          // Make sure that the interval is destroyed too
          $scope.stopFight();
        });
      }])
    // Register the 'myCurrentTime' directive factory method.
    // We inject $interval and dateFilter service since the factory method is DI.
    .directive('myCurrentTime', ['$interval', 'dateFilter',
      function($interval, dateFilter) {
        // return the directive link function. (compile function not needed)
        return function(scope, element, attrs) {
          var format,  // date format
              stopTime; // so that we can cancel the time updates

          // used to update the UI
          function updateTime() {
            element.text(dateFilter(new Date(), format));
          }

          // watch the expression, and update the UI on change.
          scope.$watch(attrs.myCurrentTime, function(value) {
            format = value;
            updateTime();
          });

          stopTime = $interval(updateTime, 1000);

          // listen on DOM destroy (removal) event, and cancel the next UI update
          // to prevent updating time after the DOM element was removed.
          element.on('$destroy', function() {
            $interval.cancel(stopTime);
          });
        }
      }]);
</script>

<div>
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <label>Date format: <input ng-model="format"></label> <hr/>
    Current time is: <span my-current-time="format"></span>
    <hr/>
    Blood 1 : <font color='red'>{{blood_1}}</font>
    Blood 2 : <font color='red'>{{blood_2}}</font>
    <button type="button" data-ng-click="fight()">Fight</button>
    <button type="button" data-ng-click="stopFight()">StopFight</button>
    <button type="button" data-ng-click="resetFight()">resetFight</button>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```